# Firebase Analytics, Are prescribed event parameters also counted as custom parameters?

Tags: firebase, analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm setting up Firebase analytics for my app for both android and ios. I just learned that there's a 50 custom parameters limit I can create, also learned there are prescribed event parameters that firebase suggests with recommended events.

My question is, are these prescribed parameters counted as custom parameters when used?

My guess is yes, but I want to be clear before I actually start coding and possibly mess up with the number of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "custom parameters" do you mean **custom parameters** in event? If that's the case then limit is 25 per event.

Maybe you thought about custom parameters in reporting? Then the limit is [indeed 50](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en), but it is **only for reporting.**

If you ask about [user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317519?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489) then the limit is 25 per app and no - predefined/default user properties don't count, so you can add 25 user properties yourself.

As a general rule - usually default stuff doesn't count for limits.

For more info on up-to-date limits see here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9237506

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. What is the difference in counting parameters for reporting and non-reporting?

Comment: Reporting purposes mean that you register your custom property in Firebase console and it is displayed in your UI - you can have up to 50 of that kind of properties. But every of your custom event in app (up to 500) can have 25 custom parameters *each*. They will not be displayed in Firebase console data analysis, but they are still stored and you can access them via BigQuery - if you want to do some additional analysis.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the answer!